# MiGLayout will not expand JPanel down

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, miglayout, jtoolbar

As I am sure some of you are aware, I am attempting to make an alernative tool to Tiled that is open source. I asked before what layout I should use and I was suggest the MiGLayout which I really do love, but don't understand that well at all. I also hope to learn something from this as well. **What I would like is someone to explain to me what I did wrong, obviously, and what I need to do to correct this.**

Let me first state what works perfect in my eyes, but may not really.

- JFrame
- Menu & Menu Items

Now let me state what I don't like and is not bending to my will.

- JToolBar (There are gaps I don't want, they are circled in red)
- Both JPanels (The width it prefect, but they are not filling to the height)

My question is **what can I do to fix this** and **how can I make the miglayout adjust so that when the toolbar is moved it doesn't make the layout fall to pieces?**

Here is my code:

```
package main;

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JToolBar;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;

import net.miginfocom.swing.MigLayout;

public class GUI extends JFrame {

    // Window Vars //
    String title;
    int width;
    int height;

    // Mid Level componets //
    JMenuBar menuBar;
    JMenu file;
    JToolBar toolBar;
    JPanel map;
    JPanel sideBar;

    // Low Level componets //
    JMenuItem exit;

    JButton select;

    public GUI(String title, int width, int height) {
        this.title = title;
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
        this.makeInterface();
    }

    public void makeInterface() {
        // Setup JFrame
        this.setTitle(title);
        this.setSize(width, height);
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        this.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(700, 500));
        this.setVisible(true);

        this.setLayout(new MigLayout(
                "debug, fillx, gap unrel rel",  // Layout
                "[grow, fill][fill]",         // Column
                "[fill][fill]"));       // Row
        this.makeMenu();
        this.addToolBars();
        this.makePanels();
        this.setupActionListeners();
    }

    public void makeMenu() {
        this.menuBar = new JMenuBar();
        this.file = new JMenu("File");
        this.file.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_F);
        this.menuBar.add(file);

        this.exit = new JMenuItem("Exit", KeyEvent.VK_E);
        this.exit.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_E, ActionEvent.ALT_MASK));
        this.file.add(exit);

        this.setJMenuBar(this.menuBar);
    }

    public void addToolBars() {
        this.toolBar = new JToolBar("Draggable");
        this.addToolBarButtons();
        this.add(toolBar, "span, height 20:35:50, wrap");
    }

    public void addToolBarButtons() {
        this.select = new JButton("Select");
        this.toolBar.add(select);
    }

    public void makePanels() {
        this.map = new JPanel();
        this.sideBar = new JPanel();

        this.add(map, "width 400:600:, flowy, growy");
        this.add(sideBar, "width 250:300:350, flowy, growy");
    }

    public void setupActionListeners() {
        this.exit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

[image: Program in its current state]

Comment: I figured out one problem, I needed to set the row constraints to fill and grow under the second row. Still not sure what to do for the gap issue and moving the tool bar issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Needed to set the sidebar and map area in the area by using the docking feature.

For example I did as follows:

```
this.setLayout(new MigLayout(
    "fill",  // Layout
    "",         // Column
    ""));       // Row
this.add(map, "width 400:600:, dock center, growy");
this.add(sideBar, "width 250:300:350, dock east, growy");
```

This got rid of gaps and expanded everything as needed.